# Form not submitting with Laravel Collection

Tags: html, laravel, forms, laravel-collection

I'm trying to make a simple create form for a new post using Laravel v.8.

The first time I tried the form it worked fine, but after I tried to add TinyMCE using CDN online, and deleted it, the form stopped working for some reason.

**Here's my blade**

```html
<div class="box-body">
  {!! Form::model($post, [ 'method' => 'POST', 'route' => 'storepost' ]) !!}

  <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('title') ? 'hasError' : '' }}">
    {!! Form::label('title') !!} {!! Form::text('title', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
  </div>

  @if($errors->has('title'))
  <span class="help-block"> {{ $errors->first('title') }} </span> @endif

  <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('kategori') ? 'hasError' : '' }}">
    {!! Form::label('kategori') !!}
    <br> {!! Form::select('kategori', ['anime' => 'Anime', 'news' => 'News', 'medicine' => 'Medicine'], null, ['placeholder' => 'Pick a category...']) !!}
  </div>

  @if($errors->has('kategori'))
  <span class="help-block"> {{ $errors->first('kategori') }} </span> @endif

  <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('body') ? 'hasError' : '' }}">
    {!! Form::label('body') !!} {!! Form::textarea('body', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
  </div>

  @if($errors->has('body'))
  <span class="help-block"> {{ $errors->first('body') }} </span> @endif

  <div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::submit('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']); !!}
  </div>

  {!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
```

**Here's my controller**

```
public function create(Post $post)
{
    return view('layouts.backend.admin.create', compact('post'));
}
```

**This is where 'dd' doesn't work.**

```
public function store(Requests\PostRequest $request)
{
    $request->user()->posts()->create($request->all());

    return redirect('admin/all')->with('message', 'Data saved!');
}
```

**And this is my Route**

```
Route::get('/admin/create', [App\Http\Controllers\BackEnd\BlogController::class, 'create'])->name('createpost');

Route::post('/admin/store', [App\Http\Controllers\BackEnd\BlogController::class, 'store'])->name('storepost');
```

I have other routes too for update, but those worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

It was something on my PostRequest that I forgot to change.

From this:

```
'category' => 'required',
```

To this:

```
'kategori' => 'required',
```

I'm not sure why it doesn't pass as an error when there's something missing like this, though.